# Any way to use HTML, JavaScript, and ActionScript to create a Copy to Clipboard button WITHOUT using zClip?

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, air, adobe

I have no code to really display here, since I have not been able to really make a start until I've found out my answer. I've been checking all over Stack, and all over the internet, and found numerous references that seem to hint towards Adobe AIR being able to write directly to the clipboard in some fashions, but no concrete examples on how this is accomplished.

Is there ANY way to use an HTML FORM input button, or maybe a simple URL link to Copy directly to the Windows Clipboard in Adobe AIR without the use of invisible flash files overlayed over buttons (such as zClip or zeroClipboard)?

This is for an in-house application that would run on our employees computers. The idea is to be able to have a button that when clicked would run a JavaScript function to get the values of a bunch of different form fields (name, address, etc), output them to a textarea on the page, and then have that textarea automatically copied to the clipboard to be pasted into a client file.

I completely understand why copy to clipboard functionality was completely removed from JavaScript and is almost impossible to do even now with flash in a web browser, but I was hoping by using AIR which is more of a local application, I'd be able to stick to what I know (HTML and Jscript) but achieve my goal without zClip. This wouldn't be so much of a security issue I figure because it's all in-house and would never leave an employee machine.

For those wondering, the reason I don't like zClip is because it doesn't work with tab orders, I like to use just my keyboard when entering in information and tab to my submit and copy buttons, but since the zClip overlays an invisible flash file over the actual button, when you tab over to the button, it does nothing, rendering tab functionality useless.

Comment: So you want to put some arbitrary text into clipboard using AS3? (The fact that button is on html form doesn't matter, because you can make AS3 handler for JS event.)

Comment: This is my first attempt at an Air Appication. I'm a very capable HTML and JavaScript web designer, but I don't understand anything about Flex quite honestly. I found a decent example of how to combine java and actionscript here: http://blog.everythingflex.com/2008/02/25/air-actionscript-javascript-bridge/ but I don't understand how the mxml file in the reference link is supposed to be added to the AIR application. Perhaps you can help on that aspect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand the question.

If you are looking to expose clipboard functionality in Air using JS take a look at the [Adobe Air HTML reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/) - it contains a [clipboard](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html) class for use with JS Air applications.

Comment: its frustrating that I can't find any information that actually teaches the concept or explains how to do these things in an example context. I'm the kind of person that learns from reading an example of working code, not from reading an explanation of how the 2 can work together.. I want a normal clickable button in html that triggers javascript that can copy to the clipboard. Javascript can't  on its own so I need to use some sort of "bridge". Half of the pages refer to it as Flex SDK, some say Flex Builder, some say Flash Builder.. I don't understand how this is supposed to work. :-/

Comment: This is my first attempt at an Air Appication. I'm a very capable HTML and JavaScript web designer, but I don't understand anything about Flex quite honestly. I found a decent example of how to combine java and actionscript here: http://blog.everythingflex.com/2008/02/25/air-actionscript-javascript-bridge/ but I don't understand how the mxml file in the reference link is supposed to be added to the AIR application. Perhaps you can help on that aspect?

Comment: Essentially, Adobe Air is like a browser with benefits. Using the AIR APIs it allows cross-platform access to operating system operations such as, but not limited to, File manipulation.

Generally, there are two methods of creating an air app. One is to use the Adobe Flex SDK which is built on Actionscript 3 using MXML components for 'mark-up'.

The other way to go is similar to using Air as a desktop browser. You can write html, css and js as you would a web page and run it all using Adobe Air like you would a Desktop app. The added benefit is you have access to the OS. Cont...

Comment: Take a look at Adobe's guide to getting started with html / js and air: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/getting_started_air_js.html

hope this helps!

Comment: I understand the basics of creating an application.xml, having it reference a context html file, I have AIR loading my html file just fine, and my JavaScript... I just have no idea how I'm supposed to be able to use ActionScript specific arguments in my html document. I can't copy to paste with JavaScript, I need my JavaScript to also activate my ActionScript copy... The link I posted above shows how to bridge JavaScript to ActionScript, but I can't find an explanation of how I'm supposed to tie that MXML file into my app to create that "bridge".

Comment: Also, am I just totally off base with my assumption that this : http://blog.everythingflex.com/2008/02/25/air-actionscript-javascript-bridge/ is basically what I'm looking for? I'm kinda walking blind, I've read through all that reference material you and everyone else has linked already, before coming to stack (I try to do my homework before I bug an expert). I'm still no closer to understanding how I'm supposed to bridge these things together, or how to properly call AScript from JScript. It's becoming apparent that I'm overstretching, and that I may not have what it takes to grasp this...

Comment: I feel like.. I've got the 2 pieces to my puzzle already. I know how to Copy to Clipboard using ActionScript, I know how to get the values of my form fields with JavaScript, I just need to know how to get JavaScript to execute ActionScript so the user can just click one button and JavaScript handles the creation of the form, and the copy click. I must be missing something

Comment: Your are overcomplicating things. As I mentioned previously, the JAVASCRIPT AIR SDK has the ability to copy to the clipboard as well. You can build the whole application in just HTML, CSS and Javascript - you don't need actionscript or MXML.

Take a look at the second link expecially, it shows you how to import the javascript Air aliases.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/ajax/quickstart.html
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ecc.html

Comment: Ok. I really appreciate you working through this with me, I know you don't have to so believe me it's recognized. I'm loading in AIRAliases.js now, and I see that they have an air.Clipboard Alias, but I'm not sure what the proper context is to use it in. I've tried air.Clipboard.setData('test'), just air.Clipboard('test') and air.ClipboardFormats to try and get it to fire anything, but I can't seem to get the syntax right. The example uses air.trace, which works fine.. any chance you might be able to give me that TINY bit of JavaScript I'm missing that utilizes air.Clipboard to copy to clip?

Comment: There is a code sample http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html#generalClipboard in the Clipboard class docs which demonstrates how to write to and read from the clipboard. The key line to write to clipboard is `air.Clipboard.generalClipboard.setData(air.ClipboardFormats.TEXT_FORMAT, copy);` where the parameters passed in are the format of data you want to write - accessed via the ClipboardFormats constants and the data itself - in this case `copy` would be a `var` holding a string.

Comment: Dude! I did it, without your last post in fact. I just had to work it out on my head. Finally managed to get it to work with air.Clipboard.generalClipboard.setData... I was just missing the generalClipboard portion. FINALLY, I get it!!! Thank you SO much James I can never fully repay you for baby stepping me through this process.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. To their credit, a lot of Adobe's Flex and Air framework is well documented compared to some other languages so it well worth just reading through the whole class even if you don't need all the methods, it plants a seed for next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can route JS click event into AS3 handler with `ExternalInterface.addCallback()`, see [example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e92.html). Use arguments to transfer data to be pasted.
Then `Clipboard.generalClipboard.setData()` can paste data in text format. See [example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html#includeExamplesSummary) on Adobe docs.